# Retrieving custom Future Android Ion by Koush

Tags: android

am new to Android. Sorry if this question is too simple. I have tried searching for a solution for weeks now. I am using Ion from https://github.com/koush/ion in my project. Uploads and downloads work well but when it comes to retrieving a specific custom Future after resuming the app I get stuck. I want to retrieve a single operation say an upload and stop it without affecting other uploads or vice versa for downloads.

Comment: Add some code you have tired?

Comment: I have tried the code below. But after exiting the app, there is no way for me to get the asycProcess instance so as to cancel it. asycProcess = Ion
    .with(context)
    .load("POST", url)
    .setTimeout(60 * 60 * 1000)
    .setMultipartParameter("number", clicked_contact_number)
    .setMultipartFile("uploaded_file", "*/*", fileToUpload)
    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
     @Override
     public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
     // on complete code
     }

    });

Comment: What "*code below*"? And what do you mean by "*there is no way for me to get the*"?

Comment: sorry, wasnt done with the comment. Please reread it

Comment: hey @SamSwift웃, sorry for the very delayed reply. I forgot I ever posted a question here. Kindly note that I was actually doing things the wrong way and later on figured it out. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to implement a broadcast receiver within creation of the process that returns a Future callback. This will allow you to cancel/stop its operation by just triggering the broadcast receiver

```
 // set broadcast listeners
    BroadcastReceiver broadcast = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String cancelled_msg_time = intent.getStringExtra("time");

            // check if this download was cancelled
            if (my_time.equals(cancelled_msg_time)) {

                if (upload_started) {
                    // cancel asynctask
                    asycProcess.cancel(true);
                }

                // set flag as cancelled
                cancelled = true;
            }
        }
    };

    // register the broadcast receiver to cancel downloads
    IntentFilter intent_filter = new IntentFilter();
    intent_filter.addAction("CANCEL_UPLOAD");
    context.registerReceiver(broadcast, intent_filter);
```

Then your execution should somehow check status if it has been cancelled before proceeding

```
 if (!cancelled) {
            file_progress_handler = new FileProgressHandler();
            // proceed with upload
        }
```